# A circle with circumference 1 spins around a triangle with sides of 1. How many turns does the circle make if it rolls once around the triangle?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

> A circle with circumference 1 spins around a triangle with sides of 1. How many turns does the circle make if it rolls once around the triangle?

I tried to solve this question; my answer was $3$ but it turns out the answer was $4$. I don't understand why. Is it because when the circle turns a corner that account for that extra turn. (What I mean is that after turning around each corner it adds and extra 1/3 of a revolution.)

Thanks for anybody that can help.

Comment: The difficulty with this problem is that you can't really attack the problem without *visualizing* the movement of the circle.  I advise cutting out a circle and a triangle from (for example) cardboard, with a scissors, using a pen to mark a specific point on the circle, and then rolling the circle around the triangle.  This will allow you to visualize what is happening, which should stretch your intuition.

Comment: Please incorporate the problem statement, currently given only in the title, into the body of your Question.

Comment: Consider also the case [when a coin rolls around an identical stationary coin](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/149234/89922), how many turns would the moving coin make?

Comment: It makes 4 rotations - one for each side and then 1/3 for each corner.

Comment: I don't know why it turns exactly 1/3 for each corner. Is it something to do with the size of the angle?

Comment: @user2661923 This is from the Junior Mathematics Competition that has 25 questions in 60 minutes.  There is no time to cut out and visualize the circle's movements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many turns does a circle of circumference 1m make as it rolls around an equilateral triangle of perimeter 3m?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3634665/how-many-turns-does-a-circle-of-circumference-1m-make-as-it-rolls-around-an-equi) That question is linked under *Related* on the right-hand side of this page, which is why it's always a good idea to check that, first.

Comment: It was not clear enough